# Access custom control compositeData value through java bean

Tags: java, xpages

See there a way to access xpages custom control compositeData value from a java bean ?

Thanks
Bob

Comment: How do you intend to use it? Usually, you create a Java bean and then you can call its methods from JavaScript, e.g. myBean.setSomeValue(compositeData.someValue)

Comment: Theoretical question, for a project I'm working on, were I have many composite data values I want to pass to the bean.

Comment: Instead of the many compositeData values, cannot you put the values in the bean and pass the bean itself? I had a similar thing, one custom control with lots of parameters, until I created the bean first with the necessary properties and used that to pass to the custom control.

Comment: Interesting, can you give some details and possible an example.  Maybe used that in conjunction with a resource property file.

Comment: Hm, not easy. Our CC (ccField) is a field in a form, with lots of properties (type, font, etc). We used to pass every parameter to the CC separately. Now we create one bean per field, it loads its properties from the form definition and then I pass the bean to ccField. The bean is a plain Java bean, nothing really fancy.